Ao adicionar meus componentes no arquivo app.routes.ts no angular 18, e gerando uma build não está sendo criado o arquivo index.html
Ao adicionar meus componentes no arquivo app.routes.ts no Angular 18 e gerar a build com o comando ng build, o arquivo index.html não está sendo gerado.
export const routes: Routes = [
// Ao remover arquivos o arquivo index.html é gerado normalmente
{path: "login", component: LoginComponent},
{path: "cadastro", component: CadastroComponent },
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
{path: '',   redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

Eu me deparei com o mesmo problema, minha solução foi refazer o projeto utilizando a versão 17.3.0 do cli do angular ao invés da versão 18 que eu estava utilizando antes.
